# Let $f(x) = \frac{3x^2 + mx + n}{x^2 + 1}$. If the range of the function is $[-4, 3]$ then find $m$ and $n$.

Tags: functions

The given function is:

$$f(x) = \frac{3x^2 + mx + n}{x^2 + 1}$$
$$y = \frac{3x^2 + mx + n}{x^2 + 1}$$
By cross-multiplying,
$$ yx^2 + y = 3x^2 + mx + n$$
$$x^2(y-3) - mx + (y - n) = 0$$
 We know that the domain is $x \in R$. Hence, $Δ ≥ 0$.
$$m^2 - 4(y-n)(y-3) ≥ 0$$
$$(y-n)(y-3) ≤ \frac{m^2}{4}$$

After this, I don't know how to proceed further.

It would be nice if you could give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second last step,  I shall continue. 
We have, 
$$m^2-4(y-n)(y-3)\geq 0$$
Which on rearranging gives:
$$4y^2-(4n+12)y + 12n-m^2 \leq 0$$
Suppose that the roots of the quadratic in the LHS are $a, b$,  with $a<b$.  So now we have, 
$$(y-a) (y-b) \leq 0$$ 
Which is simply $y\in [a, b]$. But we have $y\in [-4,3]$, implying $a=-4, b=3$.

Also,  $a+b=n+3=-1\Rightarrow n=-4$ and $ab=\frac{12n-m^2} {4} =-12\Rightarrow m^2 =0$ i. e. $m=0$

So there you have it: $n=-4, m=0$. Ta-da!

Answer (score 1):

$$ 4y^2-4(n+3)y+12n\le m^2$$

Now if $$(x-a)(x-b)\le0\text{ with } a<b,$$
 we can conclude $$ a\le x\le b$$

The roots of
$$y^2-(n+3)y+\dfrac{12n-m^2}4=0$$

are $$\dfrac{n+3\pm\sqrt{n^2-6n+m^2+9}}2$$

As $\sqrt{(n-3)^2+m^2}\ge0,$

$\implies\dfrac{n+3+\sqrt{(n-3)^2+m^2}}2=3$

$\dfrac{n+3-\sqrt{(n-3)^2+m^2}}2=-4$